# Slow internet connection with mobile broadband

Tags: 10.10, broadband, internet-connection

I'm using a Huawei 156g USB stick to connect to the internet. In windows it reacts lightning fast and loads pages faster than my Ubuntu 10.10 does, It's not the connection type (HSDPA, WCDMA or gsm) it takes more time to connect, download speed seems okay (But not full speed i think) what is the matter with it? do I need to install some kind of drivers for it? I'm not behind a proxy. please help, I just searched around ask Ubuntu and nothing matched my problem :-(

Comment: What did you do to install the 156G USB stick, simply plug it in? When I searched for 'Huawei 156g USB ubuntu' a number of blog and forum posts came up with configuration and installation instructions came up for various versions of Ubuntu. What have you tried to make this work, besides plugging it in?

Comment: Mmm.. no. you have misunderstood my question. the modem is installed properly. the problem is browsing through it!. I have configured it to fit the operator well. and it just connects to the Internet in no time.  Pages take more time to load than windows here. Is it normal?, the loading icon just rotate counterclockwise about 6-10 seconds!.in windows it's about 1-2 seconds!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! it isn't a problem with the modem, it's a bug in the 10.10 system and I switched to new 11.10 and now my net speed boosts more than windows do! thanks anyway for the help from you guys!